# How to use IBus instead of GNOME's input method manager on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ibus

I followed the steps in the IBus GitHub wiki but it doesn't work. I can open the `ibus-setup` window and set 2 languages but I can't switch between them, I'm stuck on english input method.

[image]

I need Ibus to make a bash script for changing my input method automatically.